# about data definitions scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am being asked to provide a data definition for a list of images. That's it. I am confused. This seems a bit vague to me.   What exactly do they mean by this?

Comment: Whats the context, environment/languages/images types?

Comment: Any relationship with this? http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
A list-of-numbers is
    either   empty      
    or       (cons n lon),
where n is anumber and lon is a list-of-numbers.
```